# Representations of gamma matrices

Tags: quantum-field-theory, homework-and-exercises

I have to do this exercise for homework. Find a representation of the gamma matrices unitarily connected to the standard representation for wich the spinors $u(p)$ that satisfy the equation $(p_\mu \gamma^\mu - m)u(p)=0$ of motion for a generic momentum $p^2=m^2$ have only the first two components different from zero.
I tried to find the transformation $V$ such that $Vu(p)$ meet the demand but was not able to complete my idea. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: think about what it means if two components only are non-zero. you could write this than not as four-component, but two component objects.

Answer (score 4):

From the FAQ:

> However, we do not allow certain kinds of questions:
>
> •"Do my homework"-type physics questions
> "A 4kg ball is traveling at 8m/s in the x direction, how do I find..."
> Physics - Stack Exchange is not a homework help site. If you have a question about a homework problem, or any problem of an educational nature, narrow it down to the specific concept that is giving you trouble and ask about that. You can find more information about acceptable homework questions on our meta site.

I think you might be okay if you reworded your question and discussed your idea a bit, but it seems to me that this is a bit too overt.